# Generate Database Schema using Python

Tags: python, database, django, schema

I want to generate a basic DB schema for my django project to display all my Apps with Models and Model Fields with boundary conditions etc. Is there already any DB schema generator for django in python? Or otherwise how should i go about doing it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your talking about needing to see the SQL schema, run `./manage.py sqlall <appname>`

If you want a visualisation of the schema you can get `django-extensions` and run `./manage.py graph_models -a -g -o my_project.png`. This will produce a pretty schema graph for you, but generally omits border conditions. you may want to check the options to add more data. http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-extensions/en/latest/graph_models.html

Answer (score 5):

`manage.py sql <appname appname ...>` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#sql-appname-appname))

Answer (score 2):

### Using Your DB

As mentioned in the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/#database-setup), you can use your database's command line client to get the schema.

Example using sqlite:

```
python manage.py dbshell
> .schema
```

You may need to install sqlite3 for this to work.

### Using Django

You used to be able to use `python manage.py sql ...`, but it has been deprecated in 1.9 in favor of migrations. You can check out the initial migration scripts using:

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate myapp 0001_initial
```

(From [Answer: Equivalent of sqlall in Django 1.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35455883/461834))